# Make fire float up

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl

```
// this is the display function it is called when ever you want to draw something all drawing should be called form here
void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    // draw background 
    drawBackground();
    glPushMatrix();
    // draw hot air balloon
    drawAirBalloon();
    // draw spray
    drawSpray();
    glPopMatrix();
    // draw rain
    drawRain();
    // draw fire
    drawSpray();
    calcFPS();
    counter++;
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

The problem is that I can't make the fire go up with my hot air balloon. The reason why I only put the code above (display) is because I think the problem is to do with this particular code.

To see the full code, click on the link below:

[hot air balloon code](http://cpp.sh/3ag5i)

This is the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you set the model view matrix to the identity matrix in the function `circle`.

Replace [`glLoadIdentity`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glLoadIdentity.xml) by [`glPushMatrix()`/`glPopMatrix()`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glPushMatrix.xml) in the function `circle()`:

```
void circle(double radius, double xc, double yc) {
      int i;
      double angle = 2 * 3.1415 / 20;   // circle is drawn using 20 line.
      double circle_xy[100][40];
      circle_xy[0][0] = radius + xc;
      circle_xy[0][1] = yc;
      glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); 
      glPushMatrix();
      // set fire position
      glTranslatef(-40.0, 60.0, 0.0);
      glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
      for (i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
          circle_xy[i][0] = radius * cos(i * angle) + xc;
          circle_xy[i][1] = radius * sin(i * angle) + yc;
          glVertex2f(circle_xy[i - 1][0], circle_xy[i - 1][1]);
          glVertex2f(circle_xy[i][0], circle_xy[i][1]);
      }
      glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

To make the code more comprehensible, I recommend to remove [`glTranslatef`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) for `drawAirBalloon`, but to do it in `display`:

```
void drawAirBalloon(void) {
    // glTranslatef(squareX, squareY, squareZ); <--- remove

    // ....
} 

void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    // draw background 
    drawBackground();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(squareX, squareY, squareZ); // <--- insert
    // draw spray
    drawSpray();
    // draw hot air balloon
    drawAirBalloon();
    glPopMatrix();

    // draw rain
    drawRain();
    calcFPS();
    counter++;
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

---

You do a lot of effort and you write a lot of tricky and well structured code. I relay recommend, to read about [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) and [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader). Go on, but start to get rid of the deprecated fixed function pipeline and switch to a moder way of rendering.

Comment: How do I put the balloon in front of the fire?

Comment: @Muddy swap `drawSpray` and `drawAirBalloon`. I swapped it in the answer, just now.